# Designing a context free grammar for a language; When to use the empty string

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, strings

$L= \{a^{2i}b^{j}vc^{j}(ac)^{i} |  i,j \ge 0, v \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$

How can a grammar be created from the language without the use of the empty string. Below is my example that does use the empty string.

$S \rightarrow aaSac|B$

$B \rightarrow bBc|C$

$C \rightarrow aC|bC|\epsilon $

Comment: Is it a requirement to create the grammar without empty string?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I am sort of confused about that. Given my information provided in the question, does anything state that the grammar needs to be created without the empty string? Do the alphabet of the language or the values that $v$ can have affect the presence of the empty string in the grammar? Is it even possible to create the grammar without the empty string.

Comment: If we assume, yes, there is a restriction on using $\epsilon$, then what would the grammar look like.

Comment: What do you mean by "a conceptualized Context-free Grammar"? I have never heard of that. Do you just mean "a Context-free Grammar"?

Comment: conceptualized is meant to mean, that I conceptualized the Grammar from the Language, that is, the grammar may have mistakes because it was created by me. Perhaps a different word would fit better.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I see no difference in using epsilon in 'S' compared to using it any other rule. It is being used regardless, so then doesn't that mean that epsilon is a requirement to have in the Grammar?

Comment: You said "no difference in using epsilon in 'S' compared to using it any other" nonterminal symbol. Yes, there is one critical difference.

Comment: Without that one rule, you cannot let your grammar generate the empty string. We can design any other terminal symbols so that they will not (need to) generate the empty string. However, you cannot stipulate that the start symbol will not (need to) generate the empty string.

Comment: @Apass.Jack There is no specification from any instructor, this is a general question. The quesiton is: Does any information from my opening question (such as any of the sets, kleene star, language, etc.) explicitly IMPLY that the empty string does/doesn't need to be included in the grammar? You are asking me if natural requirements are specifying me to include/exclude the empty string, but the answer is I myself do not know. Any information I have about the question is in the opening post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the empty string, $\epsilon$ liberally. It could help you conceptualize the grammar easier and faster. For example, as you said, because $v\in\{a,b\}^∗$ that v can be one of $a,b$ or $\epsilon$, therefore using $\epsilon$ will help you to isolate non-terminal symbol $v$ as generating all words over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ using just three rules.

On the other hand, language $L$ in the question, $L= \{a^{2i}b^{j}vc^{j}(ac)^{i} |  i,j \ge 0, v \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ can be generated by a context-free grammar without $\epsilon$ except one rule, $S\to\epsilon$. Here it is.

$S \rightarrow aaSac|B|aaac|\epsilon$
$B \rightarrow bBc|B|bc$
$C \rightarrow aC|bC|a|b$

You can obtain the above grammar by following [the procedure to eliminate ε-rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#DEL:_Eliminate_%CE%B5-rules), which can change any context-free grammar to an equivalent grammar that either does not use $\epsilon$ or just uses it once in the rule $S\to\epsilon$.  Note that if the language includes the empty string, at least one usage of $\epsilon$ is inevitable; otherwise, it can only generate non-empty words. Finally, a grammar in Chomsky Normal form is designed to be such a grammar.

Just in case you might think every context-free grammar will use $\epsilon$ at least once, here is a grammar that does not use $\epsilon$.

$S\to a$.

In fact, for every grammar in Chomsky Normal form that uses $\epsilon$, you can remove that single rule, $S\to\epsilon$ to obtain a new grammar that does not use $\epsilon$. The languages generated by these two grammars are the same except the former one contains the empty string while the latter one does not.

Comment: Great answer, everything is well defined and easy to follow. Thanks!